# Angular 2 - Not showing authorization screen

Tags: angular, typescript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to create a login function where the User logs in via LinkedIn, grants permission to some profile data and returns the object holding this information.

Now I created my app following the [Javascript SDK - Getting Started](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk). And the [Sign In with LinkedIn (Javascript SDK)](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin) which tells me 2 different options.

First one is `IN.User.authorize(callbackFunction, callbackScope)` which is discussed in the Getting Started.

Second one is having a `<script type="in/Login"></script>` in your HTML, which would create a login button.

I tried both
The first one (Getting Started) does show the authorization screen but the problem is that it will just set a cookie in the browser, showing that a succesfull validation happened. (calling `IN.User.isAuthorized()` returns `true`).

The problem with the second one (Sign in with LinkedIn) is that no button is shown in my browser (Chrome) so I have nothing to click on. Here is my code: (removed API key)

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      LinkedIN
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2> LinkedIn login test </h2>

  <!-- option 2 -- Sign in with LinkedIn docs -->
  <script type="in/Login"></script>

  <!-- option 1 -- check typescript -->
  <button (click)="authorize()">Linkedin</button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var IN;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    IN.Event.on('auth', () => {
      console.log("authing");  // never printed
      IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }).error((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    });

  }

  authorize() {
    // note: I figured data is an empty object ({}). Nothing returned
    IN.User.authorize((data) => {
      console.log("data is "+ JSON.stringify(data)); //[object, Object]
      console.log("DATA: "+ data.firstName);         //undefined
      console.log("hl: "+ data.headLine);            //undefined
    });

    console.log("AUTH: "+IN.User.isAuthorized());    //true if succesfull
  }

}
```

**index.html (just the head - nothing else changed from default)**

```
<head>
  .... 
  <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
      api_key: 1234apikey5678
  </script>
  ....
</head>
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. If you haven't already install ionic and cordova `npm install -g ionic cordova`
2. create an empty project `ionic start myApp blank --v2 --ts`
3. register a LinkedIn app (set callback) - copy the client-id
4. adjust the 3 files so they look like shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `IN.User.authorize` doesn't provide data to the callback but the `IN.Raw.api` can be called to retrieve the data. Bit arbitrary work tbh but it works.